# Phpmyadmin blob php image coming out encrypted, want to display blob images to webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Problem resides here:

[image]

The code comes out encrypted so I'm unable to display blob images to the webpage, I would like the blob to be displaying as an image:

```
<?php
//connect to server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

//connect to database
mysql_select_db("website");

//query the database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM homepage");

//fetch results of database and convert to an array

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
//

    echo "<div class = 'productBox1'>";
        echo "<img class = 'pImg1' src='{$rows['image']}' />";
        echo "<div class = 'pDesk1'>" . "<p>" . $rows['description'] . "</p>" . "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
//
endwhile;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this into your php code

```
$rows['image'] = base64_decode($rows['image']);
```

EDIT: Make sure you are putting the images into the database using

```
$image = base64_encode($image);
```

Answer (score 0):

edit while loop with this.

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$rows['image'] = base64_decode($rows['image']);
$image = $rows['image'];
$desc = $rows['description'];
?>
echo "<div class = 'productBox1'>";
    echo "<img class = 'pImg1' src=<?php echo $image;?> />";
    echo "<div class = 'pDesk1'>" . "<p>" . $desc . "</p>" . "</div>";
echo "</div>";
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change array to assoc and see if that helps (:
so your while loop will look like this 
`while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)):`

Comment: @user3135672 Try changing the table structure from blob to longtext, then if that doesnt work, do you mind sharing the table structure? I will try figure it out by seeing what is going wrong from my computer.